# Fuzzy set working directory from bookmarked directories in vim

Tags: vim, vim-fzf

Sometimes I need to change the current working directory to a different location (e.g. to search in different project). This can for example be achived with `lcd /path/to/dir`. 
However writing out paths is ofter too slow and I often find myself using the same locations.
Ideally I'd have a fuzzy finder such as [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) popping up with a preset list of bookmarked directories to choose from. Fuzzy searching would allow to quickly select and change the working dir (obviously without changing the current file it was called from).

Shortly, I'm looking for the equivalent of the [fzf-marks](https://github.com/urbainvaes/fzf-marks) tool for vim.

Comment: [ctrlp](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having done some more [reading](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/README-VIM.md), I've found in fact a way to integrate to fzf-marks into vim, (which also work nicely without fzf-marks).

All you need is a file listing bookmarked directories, with a variable pointing at it, e.g. `FZF_MARKS_FILE="${HOME}/.fzf-marks`

This file is formatted as follows, `cat $FZF_MARKS_FILE`:

```
project1 : /home/user/project1/code
project2 : /home/user/project2/code
vimswapdir : /home/user/.local/share/nvim/swap
rlibsloc : /home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library
trash : /home/user/.local/share/Trash/files
vim-plugins : /home/user/.config/nvim/plugged
```

The idea now is to load and parse it similar to as its done in fzf-marks [jump function](https://github.com/urbainvaes/fzf-marks/blob/master/fzf-marks.plugin.zsh#L118) and make it fuzzy searchable for quick access defining a function `FM`:

```
command! -bang FM call fzf#run(fzf#wrap({'source': 'cat ~/.fzf-marks | sed "s/.*: \(.*\)$/\1/" | sed "s#~#${HOME}#"', 'sink': 'lcd'}, <bang>0))
```

Calling `:FM` now pops up a fzf window with the bookmarked directories to select from.

## Use case (which I often find myself):

Say I've started editing a file somewhere (say in `~/myproject`), but needed to search (`:grep`) for a sentence containing the word `foo` which I know is in a file within `/home/user/project1/code`. I never quite can remember the path of project1, just that is has `code` in its path. For that reason I've bookmarked it (see above).

Previously, have to somewhere look up the path and type it into vim i.e. typing `:grep foo /home/user/project1/code`. Now this works quicker as follows:

`:FM` in vim, bringing up up the list of bookmarked directories, typing bits of `code`, e.g. `co` quickly confines the search:

[image]

selecting the first line does set the current directory to `project1` (which can be confirmed by `:pwd`) but leaving the edited file as it is. Now, `:grep! foo` does indeed search recursively in project1.

Having finished the search, I can reset the working dir to the current files dir `:cd %:h` or it's root with [rooter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-rooter): `:Rooter`.

Answer (score 0):

My [ctrlp](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) conf, especially for `cache_dir` and `let g:ctrlp_cmd = 'CtrlPMixed'`

```
    " Open buffer here
    let g:ctrlp_switch_buffer = ''
    " Cache
    let g:ctrlp_cache_dir ='$h/.cache/ctrlp'
    " replace $home by ~ in cache
    let g:ctrlp_tilde_homedir = 1
    let g:ctrlp_mruf_max = 50000
    " Use ag <- grep
    " if executable('ag')
    "   let g:ctrl_user_command = 'ag %s -l --nocolor -g ""'
    " endif
    " Ignore
    let g:ctrlp_cutom_ignore = {
      \ 'dir': '\.git$,undo/',
      \ 'file': 'log'
    \ }
    if $os !=? 'termux'
      " E like edit and closer to ctrl + <c-p> used to paste
      let g:ctrlp_map = '<C-E>'
      vnoremap <C-E> :<C-u>CtrlPMixed<CR>
    else
      " Because move up gives c-e
      let g:ctrlp_map = ',e'
    endif
    " Keep cache
    let g:ctrlp_clear_cache_on_exit = 0
    " Mixed to search in MRU, FIles, Buffers
    let g:ctrlp_types = ['buf', 'mru', 'fil']
    let g:ctrlp_cmd = 'CtrlPMixed'
    " Faster listing <- vim.globpath
    if $os ==? 'windows'
      let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'dir %s /-n /b /s /a-d'
    else
      let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'find %s -type f'
    endif
```

Comment: For those not familiar with Ctrlp (like me), it is not obvious on how to actually solve the problem. How and where are the bookmarks are used? How to you actually invoke it and what does it do (e.g. does it use fzf)?...

Comment: Bookmarks are not actually used. You must edit them by hand (or map) in the cache directory. To invoke `ctrlp` you install it as a plugin, then you press `<Ctrl-P>`. It does not used `fzf` but `find` and vim regexp engine.

Comment: I must learn `fzf` but cannot you plug `fzf-mark` to vim directly ? https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/README-VIM.md

Comment: Indeed, I thought in the same line, but thought someone has made this work already to share it here. Anyway, `ctrlp` seems not the desired solution due to the absence of bookmarks and fzf.

Comment: I'd be glad to read a nice `fzf` vim integration tuto too. `Ctrlp` is awesome but is not present in shell